# Override Cakephp 3 core class

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I'd like to override a function that exists in the CakePHP 3 core (to be more specific `Cake\Database\ValueBinder`).

How can I achieve this? I tried copying the class to `src/Database/` and changed the namespace from Cake to App. I use'd the class in `AppController`, but had no luck.

Thanks in advance

Adrian

Comment: To me this sounds as if you don't really know what you are actually trying to do. You'll most probably get better help if you'd describe the actual problem that you are trying to solve by "overriding a core class"

Comment: @ndm thanks for your answer, but I'm having a use case where I do need to override this specific class. Sadly your answer does neither help nor answer my question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't actually need to do that (custom/extended value binders can be assigned to query objects out of the box already). However, in any case you should explain your use case, in order for anyone to be able to give you a proper answer.

Comment: @ndm well that sounds more like it. I did not find an option to use own value binders in the CakePHP Book / API. How to do this? Can I set my own value binder as the default value binder?

Comment: Yes you can, by creating an extended Query class with an overriden valueBinder() method. The custom query class can be made the default by overriding Table::query(). If you need the lower level access to be affected too, you'd need to create (and use) an extended datasource Connection class and override Connection::newQuery().

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. This solves it for me. Stupid me I didn't think of overriding it in my AppTable that i use for everything... 
However I didn't know of Connection::newQuery(), that's very useful!

Would you like to put this into an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

ndm helped me a lot with this (see comments to my question), but since he didn't post an answer I am doing this now.

---

It's possible to use an own `ValueBinder` by setting it on my query: `$this->Table->find()->valueBinder(myOwnValueBinder)`.

To make that the default ValueBinder in my own code (sufficient in most cases) one can use e.g. an `AppTable` as known from CakePHP 2 that extends to `Table` and make all other `*Table` classes extend  `AppTable`. Now one only needs to create the following method:

```
public function query() {
    return parent::query()->valueBinder(myOwnValueBinder);
}
```

In case it's needed that all code uses teh custom `ValueBinder`, an extended datasource Connection class has to be created (and used). In this class `Connection::newQuery()` has to be overriden.